# Plural geschrieben aber singular gemeint

Tags: word-usage

> Als Beispiel lässt es sich hervorheben, dass wenn x den Wert 60 hätte,
>   das Resultat und somit der Prozentsatz dann 50 **wäre**.

Mich interessiert das letzte Wort und zwar *wäre*. Ich erwähne zwar zwei Elemente wie *Resultat* und *Prozentsatz*, mit *somit* meine ich aber, dass es sich nur um **ein** Element handelt. Ist hier also *wäre* korrekt oder müsste es doch *wären* heissen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ihr Gedankengang ist richtig.

*Wären* das Resultat und der Prozentsatz verschiedene Größen und könnten potentiell unterschiedliche Werte annehmen, dann müsste der Plural stehen:

> […] dass, wenn *x* den Wert 60 hätte, **das Resultat und der Prozentsatz** dann 50 **wären**.
>   
>   <sub>(Beachten Sie das Komma hinter *dass*.)</sub>

Mit *sowohl … als auch* lässt sich das eindeutiger formulieren:

> […] dass, wenn *x* den Wert 60 hätte, **sowohl das Resultat als auch der Prozentsatz** dann 50 **wären**.

Durch *somit* wird allerdings klar, dass der Prozentsatz selbst das Resultat ist. Es handelt sich also um ein und dieselbe Größe. Daher muss der Singular stehen:

> […] dass, wenn *x* den Wert 60 hätte, **das Resultat und somit der Prozentsatz** dann 50 **wäre**.

Comment: Das hilft mir schonmal sehr viel. Dankeschön!